# API docs are confusing -- Node.JS

Tags: node.js

I got this on fs.rename from the docs -- http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

> fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)
>
> Explanation:
>
> Asynchronous rename(2). No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback.

However I don't really understand what this is because I am new to programming.  Its a 2 word explanation with the explanation containing the word that it needs to explain:

What is fs.**rename**, Asynchronous **rename**.

I find this a bit annoying and confusing.

Same goes for this:

> fs.**ftruncate**(fd, len, callback)
>
> Explanation:
>
> Asynchronous **ftruncate**(2).

A huge amount of the node api docs are like this and its giving me a hard time.  Is there a better resource I can use to understand what these mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "asynchronous rename", it's "asynchronous [`rename(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename)". The number in parens refers to the man page section it is found in, and section 2 is system calls. You are expected to read the man page (`man 2 rename` in a terminal) in order to learn about the original synchronous function. The same applies to [`ftruncate(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ftruncate).

Comment: It would be better if you would note that both `rename` and `fturncate` are C functions from the C standard library. While most old-school programmers would immediately recognize `fturncate` a lot of people starting to learn programming these days don't know C so they won't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Zachooz: `man` is the name of a program. It's the original online documentation system for Unix and is available on Linux and MacOS X. If you are on windows or don't have man installed then yes, use that website